# PHP radom array values from another array

Tags: php, arrays, random

**///PROBLEM SOLVED. SEE MY ANSWER BELLOW.///**

> I have an array that randomly generates TRUE values throughout it. I
>   specified the number of TRUE values i want and it works like a charm.
>   I was toying around with it`s values and generating certain actions
>   based on wether or not the value is TRUE. Problem is i need to do this
>   again, this time using the TRUE values to form an array from which i
>   need a certain number of TRUE values.
>
> I.E.   I wanted 3 TRUE values out of 5. The code gave me the 3 TRUE
>   values on random iterations:
>
> ```
> [1]=>1;         [1]=>;
>
> [2]=>1;         [2]=>1; 
>
> [3]=>;          [3]=>1; 
>
> [4]=>;          [4]=>; 
>
> [5]=>1;         [5]=>1;
> ```
>
> This is all fine and dandy. Now i need TRUE values on 2 out of the 3
>   previous values. Consider i am taking 5 bites out of an apple. On 3
>   occasions i choke on it, from which in 2 cases i lose 2,3 teeth.
>
> I want to print the outcome.
>
> ```
> "Took a bite"
>
> "Took a bite and choked"
>
> "Took a bite"
>
> "Took a bite , choked , lost 1 tooth and got 9 left" (i have a total of 10 teeth)
>
> "Took a bite , choked , lost 2 teeth and got 7 left"
> ```
>
> This is what i need to see printed after the 3/5 and 2/3 random
>   calculations occured. If i took a bite on the [2],[4] and [5]
>   iterations, i must lose tooth 2 times randomly on those exact
>   iterations.
>
> Sorry for this example.

**///PROBLEM SOLVED. SEE MY ANSWER BELLOW.///**

2) Lastly, how can i store what happened after the code ran? Like "After you ate that apple, you choked 3 times lost 3 teeth and still got 7 left".
The way i did it does not work and returns "**me loosing 1 tooth and having 9 left despite the fact that my calculated value is 7**", not stacking the values of my ordeal.

I know these questions are silly, but i searched everywhere for information, read manuals and stuff and cannot put the pieces together...

The method used in the " random 3/5" case:

```
$spots = array();
while (count($spots) < number) {
    $rand = rand(1,36);
    if (!isset($spots[$rand])) {
        $spots[$rand] = TRUE;
    }
}
$spots = $spots + array_fill(1, number, FALSE);
ksort($spots); /// credits to Nick J.
```

Then did a `foreach($spots as $k => $v)` 
Then did my code statements, starting with `if ($v == 1), do code...`
And gave me a random 3/5 list like the one i posted first.

Thank you in advance,
Vlad

Comment: Sounds like an assignment. What have you tried so far to solve this problem? Paste that code here.

Comment: Not too much really. I tried doing the same gig inside the $spots array, but bugged out. Tried nested foreach, didn`t work. I can`t think of anything else... call me stupid :'( I guess nesting the '$spots array code' would work? didn`t try that. I don`t know if that is possibile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i edited my answer as i have found the solution to problem number 1.

The catch was to scan the array of elements that are FALSE, unset them, work with that further on as it will randomly select elements from the TRUE elements of the original array.

Hope this comes in handy. I will post the code here:

```
$spots = array();
while (count($spots) < number) {
    $rand = rand(1,constant);
    if (!isset($spots[$rand])) {
        $spots[$rand] = TRUE;
    }
}
$spots = $spots + array_fill(1, constant, FALSE);
ksort($spots);
print_r($spots) ;

foreach($spots as $v)
{
    if($v != 1)
    {
        unset($spots[array_search($v,$spots)]);
    }
}
print_r($spots);
```

If example array:

```
$spots = array("1","2","3","4","5");
```

And i want 3 random numbers to be picked (TRUE = 1 , FALSE = nothing)
then the output is:

```
[1]=>1;         

[2]=>1;         

[3]=>;          

[4]=>;           

[5]=>1;
```

If i want 2 random numbers out of the 3 just got, then the final output is:

```
[1]=>1;

[2]=>1;

[5]=>1;
```